# "Analysis" or "analyses" when using "respectively"

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I have the following sentence:

> In Sections 1 and 2, we treat the X and Y analysis respectively.

To clarify, "Section 1" is the "X analysis" and "Section 2" is the "Y analysis".

In this context, should **analysis** be pluralized to **analyses**?

I could also write:

> In Sections 1 and 2, we treat the X analysis and Y analysis respectively.

But this seems unnecessarily cluttered. Any clarifications appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it should be *analyses* (plural) in the first quote.

Comment: Note that in *"In Sections 1 and 2 ..."*, *sections* should not be capitalized. It's like *"In chapters 2 and 3, I analyze xyz"*.